# Button height distorted in Chrome browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My button appears fine in Firefox

[image: in firefox]

But the height is distorted in Chrome

[image: in Chrome]

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<input name="Submit" type="image" onclick="return CheckForm1();" class="button submit" />
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.submit {
  background-color: #1ea1e3;
  border: #1ea1e3 3px solid;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.submit:hover {
  border: #1ea1e3 3px solid;
  color: #1ea1e3;
}
```

Yes I did clear the cache.

The testing page is [here](http://bruxzir.jgallardo.me/pages/contact-bruxzir-zirconia/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `<input name="Submit" type="image" onclick="return CheckForm1();" class="button submit" />`

Why are you using `type="image"` here? What sense does that make, without actually referring an image via the `src` attribute as well?

Change that to a `type="submit"` (and change the default for `value` that your browser might use if you’re not happy with it), and it displays mostly similar already. (Adjust minor issues like font-settings, borders, padding as you like.)

Comment: Well that part of the code I did not write, so not sure why they used `type="image"`. But yes your solution worked.